# Passing 'next' to django login template via urls.py

Tags: django, django-urls

I'm trying to pass the 'next' field to my login.html template via the urls.py file using this code

This works fine:

```
urls((r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login',
    {'template_name': 'myapp/login.html'}),
```

But I don't want my redirect after login to go to the '/accounts/profile/' page, I want to go to the site root, '/'.

```
url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login',
    {'template_name': 'login.html', 'next':'/'}),
```

but I get

```
login() got an unexpected keyword argument 'next'
```

Not sure how to pass the 'next' argument via the urls function and can't seem to find other solutions, any advice?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was able to do this,

```
url(r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login',
    {'template_name': 'login.html', 'extra_context': {'next':'/'}}),
```

Answer (score 8):

So you can set the default url after login by setting LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL in your settings.py:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url

It's default value is /accounts/profile/, which is why it is redirecting there!

```
# settings.py
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
```

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to pass `next` to the view as a querystring parameter instead of a named variable:

```
url(r'^login/?next=/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login',
    {'template_name': 'login.html'}),
```

Comment: thanks! I also figured another way to do it, but your way is shorter

Comment: You're welcome. Passing `extra_context` is also a perfectly valid way of solving the problem.

Comment: actually I can't get this to work. When I go to /login/, I get a no url pattern matched error..?

Comment: Hmm. It might be the final `$` symbol. I updated the answer, but if that also doesn't work, `extra_context` will work.

Answer (score 3):

The `next` parameter should be either in the `GET` or the `POST` data for the request. In your urls.py you can only pass extra parameters to the view function itself, not to the `GET` or `POST` data.

What you should do is change the form in your login template to include the `next` parameter in the form action or to include it as a hidden field in the form:

```
<form action="<url>?next=/" method="POST"> etc.
```

Or:

```
<form action="<url>" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="next" value="/" />
    etc.
```

That, or Temuz's answer might suffice, just setting the default `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` to `'/'`.

Answer (score 0):

*setting.py*

`LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL ='home'`

i chose 'root/path' for my redirect  you could also specify yours